# Angular $routeProvider utilizando <div ng-view></div>

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes, ngroute

Galera,

estou acompanhando o livro ng-book do angular, e para fazer uma SPA, estou utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

```
 - app
   - controller
       controller.js
   - js
       main.js
   - node_modules (com os arquivos de jquery, bootstrap e angular)
   - templates
       home.html
 index.html
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Título  -->
    <title>Treinando Angular</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">    

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-view></div>

    <!-- Jquery  -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular  -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Angular Route -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>    
    <!-- Main  -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>   
    <!--Controller  -->
    <script src="controller/controller.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### main.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
            controller: "HomeController"
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

### controller.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [ ]);

app.controller("HomeController", function(){
});
```

Com isto, a minha index.html não renderiza no local da ng-view, o conteudo da página home.html. Pois ja pesquisei várias páginas, e até com angular-route.js não funciona. Estou utilizando o Browser "Chrome".

Comment: Como está seu home.html?

Answer (score 1):

Você não está chamando o "ngRoute" na sua main.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

e em sua controller você está criando novamente o "myApp", teria que ser assim:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
```

Comment: Tb utilizei assim e não está funcionando.

Comment: @AndersonMartins Você está usando as rotas do Html 5? Se sim precisa configurar o LocationProvider html5mode, caso contrario você precisará passar o "#" nas url's

Answer (score -1):

Acho que faltou o `ng-app` e o `ng-controller` no index.
Você só declara as dependências no primeiro arquivo que declara a aplicação angular. no caso só na main vai ter o `angular.module("myApp",[])` (Colchetes)

Comment: Acredito que como quero fazer uma SAP, não necessitaria de utilizar o ng-controller e o ng-app, está declarado na tag body, do index.html.